# nHibernate map a filtered bag to a single property

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, components, one-to-many, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I need to map an etity to a mater tabele of a DB.

This Entity has OneToMany with another.

I need to map a Collection othe the master entity to all rows of the Child table.

But I also need to map a Property with a single row getted from the child table and filtered by a criteria that return always only one row.

Someting like a Component but in a filtered child table.

This is My Mapping:

```
public class Test
    {
        public virtual string Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<TestItem> Items { get; set; }
        public virtual TestItem Item { get; set; }

        public Test()
        {
            Items = new List<TestItem>();
        }
    }

    public class TestItem
    {
        public virtual string Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
        public virtual string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public virtual string ItemData { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestMap : ClassMapping<Test>
    {
        public TestMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Column("IDTest"));

            //IPOTETICAL
            SomeComponent(x => x.Item, c => // How to map a filtered collection to a single property??
            {
                c.Key(k =>
                {
                    k.NotNullable(true);
                    k.Column("IDTest");
                });


                **// This Is the filter**
                c.Filter("itemsFilter", f => f.Condition("ItemCode = :itemsCodeValue"));

            }, r => r.OneToMany(m =>
            {
                m.NotFound(NotFoundMode.Exception);
                m.Class(typeof(TestItem));
            }));

            Bag(x => x.Items, c =>  // All Child Rows
            {
                c.Key(k =>
                {
                    k.NotNullable(true);
                    k.Column("IDTest");
                });
                c.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
                c.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
                c.Inverse(true);
            }, r => r.OneToMany(m =>
            {
                m.NotFound(NotFoundMode.Exception);
                m.Class(typeof(TestItem));
            }));
        }
    }

    public class TestItemMap : ClassMapping<TestItem>
    {
        public TestItemMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Column("IDTestItem"));

            ManyToOne(x => x.Test, m =>
            {
                m.Column("IDTest");
                m.NotNullable(false);
                m.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
            });

            Property(x => x.ItemCode);
            Property(x => x.ItemData);
        }
    }
```

I found something about DynamicComponent but I do not know if it is for me...

http://notherdev.blogspot.it/2012/01/mapping-by-code-dynamic-component.html

Thank You!!